# How to get the offset Vector between two Vectors in 3D Space

Tags: vector

i have two vectors in 3D Space and want to get the needed offset for x, y and z to get from Vector1 to Vector2.

How can i do that?

I am using a javascript libary for a game with vector3 and vector2 implementations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it is as easy as substracting the two vectors.